# Sum Multiple Column MS Access Via Sql Query or VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Problem:I am trying to make a Inventory Management Database on Microsoft Access 2010, and since i needed records date wise my Table looks like follows

```
 SKU   2016-03-16   2016-03-17   2016-03-18   ...   Total
 AAA   10           -5           15           ...   20
 BBB   05           05           25           ...   35
 CCC   06           -5           24           ...   25
```

This way i wanted to add records for each day, but i am unable to make a "Total" column which will total all the columns (Sum(Columns*))

I am aware of sum and groupby but that works across multiple rows i am looking for something which can do the same for column

Expected Solution: A way either by Sql Query or VBA to total all the columns for SKU AAA,BBB,CCC, if not possible to total in the same table then i am open to total the columns in a new table.

Comment: Do you know how much columns you got?

Comment: I can find that by deducting the dates (today - Dayofstart) so i will get the number of days and that will be the number of columns since everyday a new column would be added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a table is normally result of pivoting summary data. Real data would look like:

SKU, Date, Quantity
...

Then probably you would want to create a PIVOT table using SKU for rows, Date for Columns and Quantity for data (default operation is SUM). It would have the row totals by default. 
It may have been named crosstab, cross tab .. or so in Access 2010.

(you may want to do the pivoting in Excel)

Comment: That is the last option, i was hoping to find a way for totaling multiple columns.

Comment: @AngadArora - I'd make this the first option then. What do you intend to do when you hit Access's 255 column limit in a couple of months?

Comment: Hahaha then i have to agree with you, but still for my curiosity i wanted to know if that was possible :( .

Comment: Cetin Basoz right, application with your design will stop working in less than one year, you cannot have more than 255 columns. As of your question, no, Access has no Sum function for columns. It can be done only thru pivoting or manual sum like `col1 + col2 + col3 +...`

Comment: Yes, that is 'possible' but not feasible. You would create a dynamic SQL having all those column names + an expression like field1+field2...fieldN as Total and execute the SQL (how in access I am not sure).

Comment: Hmm then pivoting in Excel is a better idea, and then no matter what, one could do the pivoting with say Excel 2016's increased column count (16384?). Excel also excels < g > in pivoting large amount of data fast.

Comment: If even 16384 is not satisfactory, then you can work around with creating an HTML based table and do the pivoting calculation in code (misery with access probably, but could use a programming language).

Comment: it would be way better for you to re-design the table. like what sergey and comintern had said. your table would not last. It will be better for you to normalize your table first. You can do that just by having 3 columns.
SKU, Value, Date.

Comment: @raymondSee, sorry I didn't understand what you are proposing. I already suggested it to be SKU,Value,Date.

Comment: @SergeyS., I didn't notice your comment before. No, my design wouldn't stop after a year. It would last to the row limits of access. At any time for reporting, one would likely to filter a date range so he can do it with 255 (or 16384 with Excel 2016) - 2 dates.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I am so sorry, i didnt notice that... just havnt had my coffee yet... i was essentially answering the same answer you had.

Comment: No problem, happens to us all :)